# Content Security Policy blocking wss://chat.quickblox.com:5291

Tags: cordova, quickblox, content-security-policy

I am trying to deploy my app to iOS devices but am hitting a problem connecting to my chat endpoint at wss://chat.quickblox.com:5291

This is blocked by CSP rule and so cannot connect. I have tried editing my rule but it just creates chaos elsewhere. Can anyone offer guidance?

Thanks

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline' data: gap: https://<mysite>.azurewebsites.net; connect-src *; script-src * 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; style-src * 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; font-src * data: 'self'; img-src * data: 'self'; media-src *">

[Error] Refused to connect to wss://chat.quickblox.com:5291 because it does not appear in the connect-src directive of the Content Security Policy.
[Error] SecurityError (DOM Exception 18): The operation is insecure.
    (anonymous function) (quickblox.min.js:8:23676)
    _connect (quickblox.min.js:8:23676)
    connect (quickblox.min.js:7:28223)
    connect (quickblox.min.js:2:7321)
    connect (controllers.js:346)
    (anonymous function) (controllers.js:367)
    (anonymous function) (quickblox.min.js:2:2528)
    handleResponse (quickblox.min.js:4)
    success (quickblox.min.js:4:738)
    i (jquery.min.js:2:27071)
    fireWith (jquery.min.js:2:27830)
    z (jquery.min.js:4:11959)
    (anonymous function) (jquery.min.js:4:15509)
```

Comment: What is the _exact_ error message you receive?

Comment: Have you tried adding wss: to the connect-src as the log is suggesting you?